# iOS/Swift - Lifecycle methods causing network request collisions

Tags: ios, swift

In my application, I have a home screen. Anytime this screen is loaded, it needs to make a network request (currently using Alamofire 5.2) to fetch the latest data needed to display. I am running into this issue that I believe has to do with my implementation of view lifecycles, but I am not sure how to get around it to achieve my desired effect.

**Scenario 1**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

 NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
    self,
    selector: #selector(wokeUp),
    name: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification,
    object: nil)
}

@objc func wokeUp() {
        pageLoaded()
    }

func pageLoaded(){
    // network requests made here
}

deinit {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil)
}
```

Here I am registering the observer within viewDidLoad. The reason I need this is many of our users will not close the application. We've found on more than a few occasions that they will let the phone sleep while the application is open, so we need to make this request when the phone is woken up and immediately back at this screen. the didBecomeActiveNotification seems to be what takes care of that.

**Scenario 2**

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    pageLoaded() // same network request as example above
}
```

We also need to call this request within viewDidAppear, as there are quite a few flows where the user is brought back to this home page from another view in the application, and it's important that the request is made here as well (what the user does in the other flows has an impact of what shows up here, so we have to make sure it's updated).

The problem is that what I am finding is these two scenario will occasionally clash - our server essentially gets the same request twice, which is not ideal and causing issues. I've noticed the majority (if not all) of the problems occur when opening the application when it's no longer in memory (viewDidLoad gets called); the case of bringing the app from the background to foreground while it's still in memory is working as expected, but I have no idea what other implementation I could take to cover all of my bases here. Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Use a breakpoint or print statement to check if your deinit is called for every scenario. Sometimes memory leaks prevent deinit and thus observer aren't removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just add a simple boolean flag to your networking logic to make sure only 1 request gets fired. e.g.

```
class SomeViewController {
    private var isFetching = false
    
    ...

    func pageLoaded() {
        guard isFetching == false else {
             return 
        }

        isFetching = true

        // do some networking
        // ....

        // inside the callback / error cases
        isFetching = false
    }
}
```

depending on how big your app is, if you have many requests and/or the same request being fired on many screens. Move all your networking to another class and have this logic inside the network service rather than the viewController